Why can't I set this variable from undefined to the data I capture in the conditional statement?
What I am trying to do is move an element in accordance with the scroll top movement, once it appears in the browser. I am trying to capture an initial scroll top value and save that for some math on the object. The problem is that my variable remains undefined even though it appears to be set in the function.
I am using several scroll functions and that, and/or scope, might be my issues.
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  //function that indicates object is in view
  $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
  };

  //add class when object in is view
  jQuery(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
    if ($('.home-col-01-image').isInViewport()) {
      $('.home-col-01-image').addClass("in-view")
    } else {
      $('.home-col-01-image').removeClass("in-view")
    }
  });

  //use scrollTop to move object in parallel
  jQuery(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
    if ($(".home-col-01-image").hasClass("in-view")) {
      console.log("First initialSt: " + initialSt )
      if(initialSt == undefined) {
        var initialSt = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log("Set initialSt: " + initialSt )
      } else {
        console.log("not set initialSt: " + initialSt)
      }
      //console.log("in: ")
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      var nst = st - initialSt;
      //var nst = Math.abs(initialSt - st)
      console.log("Use initialSt: " + initialSt)
      console.log("scrollTop: " + st)
      console.log("New scrollTop: " + nst)
      if ((nst<=170) && (nst>=0)) {
        $(".home-col-01-image").css("bottom", + nst);
      }
    } else {
      //console.log("out: ")
    }

 });



});


Here is sample of the console. The first occurrence of "First initialSt" should be undefined, but the second occurrence should not. I am setting that variable and outputting it at "Set initialSt," but when it comes back around it's still undefined.
First initialSt: undefined
Set initialSt: 1047
Use initialSt: 1047
scrollTop: 1047
New scrollTop: 0
First initialSt: undefined
Set initialSt: 1048
Use initialSt: 1048
scrollTop: 1048
New scrollTop: 0

My issues is the variable not being set, not necessarily how junky my code is, or how i could be doing this better.
This is my first Stack Question, so please let me know if I should be explaining more or less. Thanks!

Aside: .bind() has been deprecated for many years, and was removed in jQuery 3.0. You should use .on().

Where do you assign initialSt? I only see you using it, never assigning it.

Rather than using a global variable, you should probably use a variable associated with the element. Use $(this).data("initialSt").

I guess i never assign the initialST? My intention was to have it only set once with the if conditional, not every time there is a scroll. i just need a number for a starting value for the math.
Where would I use "$(this).data("initialSt")" ? Instead of my var inside of the if conditional?

Yes. Use $(element).data("initialSt", newvalue) instead of initialSt = newvalue, and $(element).data("initialSt") instead of initialSt in the if conditionals.

Hmm, I'm not quite understanding what to do. If I swap those exactly has you say then i don't have an initialSt at all and it breaks on the first console.log.

You still have to assign the variable the first time somewhere. I don't know what it's supposed to be, so I can't help you with that.

I'm assuming it's something that can be different for each element that you're testing with isInViewport(), which is why I think it needs to be in the element's data.

Never mind everything I wrote above, I just found the if (initialSt == undefined) statement.

The problem is you used var initialSt. That makes it a local variable. It needs to be a global variable so it persists between calls to the function.

The idea was that initialSt was NOT set so when i checked it and found undefined i could then set it. I can't it anywhere other that after the first scroll because that is the number i need. Besides that, is there any logical reason why       if(initialSt == undefined) {         var initialSt = $(this).scrollTop();         console.log("Set initialSt: " + initialSt )       } else {         console.log("not set initialSt: " + initialSt)       }

Read my last comment again. Get rid of var. Then it will be a global variable.

Having issues with formatting that as code...

Do you understand the difference between local and global variables?

Code formatting in comments doesn't work if you have a space after the backtick.

When i removed the var none of it worked, "initialSt is not defined"

if(initialSt == undefined) {         initialSt = $(this).scrollTop();         console.log("Set initialSt: " + initialSt )       } else {         console.log("not set initialSt: " + initialSt)       }

You need to move the declaration of initialSt out of the event handler function, so it will persist between calls.
It's also 2024. Use up-to-date jQuery methods, and let rather than var to declare variables.


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //function that indicates object is in view
  $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
    let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
  };

  //add class when object in is view
  $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    if ($('.home-col-01-image').isInViewport()) {
      $('.home-col-01-image').addClass("in-view")
    } else {
      $('.home-col-01-image').removeClass("in-view")
    }
  });

  let initialSt;
  
  //use scrollTop to move object in parallel
  $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    if ($(".home-col-01-image").hasClass("in-view")) {
      console.log("First initialSt: " + initialSt)
      if (initialSt === undefined) {
        initialSt = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log("Set initialSt: " + initialSt)
      } else {
        console.log("not set initialSt: " + initialSt)
      }
      //console.log("in: ")
      let st = $(this).scrollTop();
      let nst = st - initialSt;
      //var nst = Math.abs(initialSt - st)
      console.log("Use initialSt: " + initialSt)
      console.log("scrollTop: " + st)
      console.log("New scrollTop: " + nst)
      if ((nst <= 170) && (nst >= 0)) {
        $(".home-col-01-image").css("bottom", +nst);
      }
    } else {
      //console.log("out: ")
    }
  });
});




YES! That was it. I'm not great at jQuery (got my degree here on Stack Overflow). But now i know that using "let" outside of the function makes it a global variable allowing use inside and out of various functions. Right?

It's not "really" global, it's local to the document.ready callback function. But that's good enough for this.

Thanks for the help. I had given up on it.
